# node-gyp commands in runtime not using a cmd-package

Tags: node.js, cmd, node-gyp

I want to be able to use node-gyp configure and node-gyp build without the need of using the cmd or packages such as node-cmd.

The runtime needs to be able generate the appropriate project build files for the current platform and generate the compiled .node file without the need of cmd-commands.
Is there a solution or package that can generate the same result without the need of running cmd commands?

Comment: As using an IDE ? you can try https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-tutorial

Comment: I am using an IDE, I want to do this in runtime without using any interfaces that uses bash or shell commands.

Comment: Sorry i dunno this possibility nodejs was designer for people who love repository as npm or apt so this tools run on console you can do some batch file to do the job but you still needed to edit the batch files to do for example : npm test or npm install or npm start or node index.js ... as you set.